# Creating a column from a string slice in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, slice

does somebody know why is this displaying a NaN value in the column "2_stars"?? Thanks in advance

```
data['1_star']=data['Sentiment'].str.slice(31,40)
data['start'] = data['Sentiment'].str.find("'2 stars', 'score': ") + len("'2 stars', 'score': ")
data['end'] = data['Sentiment'].str.find("}, {'label': '3 stars'")
data['2_stars']=data['Sentiment'].str.slice(data['start'],data['end'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `str.slice` working with scalars numbers, not by all columns values. So need processing per rows in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
data['2_stars']= data.apply(lambda x: x['Sentiment'][slice(x['start'], x['end'])], axis=1)
```

Another idea with list comprehension:

```
zipped = zip(data['Sentiment'], data['start'], data['end'])
data['2_stars'] = [a[slice(s, e)] for a, s, e in zipped]
```